# What additional information does careers want?

Tags: support, jobs

I got my invite to Careers 2.0 and went to log in using my Google-account open-ID info.  However, once I logged into Google, I was informed that StackExchange is requesting additional information from my Google account.

Sadly, Google doesn't tell me *what* additional information is being requested.  Nor does SE or Careers offer any hints.

First, a suggestion: I should be able to log in without having to hand over any additional information, period.  I realize Jeff has stepped away, but I find it hard to believe he'd leave in charge people who don't get this.

Second: if SE/Careers/whatever *does* want additional information, that information should be explicitly requested from me, the person, not from the provider of my OpenID.

Not that it matters, but I'd love to know what information Careers feels it must have before allowing me to log-in (other than my Open-ID credentials.)

Thanks!

Comment: I believe currently we only request for your email, but I'll have to get confirmation that is all.  Stack Overflow has been asking for this information for some time, but I am certain that Careers is not asking for anything SO doesn't already ask for.

Comment: That's great.  After I log in, you can maybe have a field to ask for my email and, if I want to fill it in, I will.  I sure as hell don't want Careers-2.0 having the email address I use with my Open-ID account!

Comment: On the careers site we actually require you to have an email in order to create an account.  We require this because we guarantee to employers this information to contact you once you have expressed some sort of interest in the position they are have open (either through search or you applying).  It's possible if we had a profile site separate from Careers, we wouldn't require this information, but for now that's not the case.

Comment: Ok, then I alter my suggestion to: don't allow search/applying without an email address (verified, if you want.)  But the email that is associated with my Open-ID provider is not the one that is available to Stack Exchange, Careers, employers (current or potential) or others.  So my *main* gripe is that you guys want to go giving away an inappropriate email address to my potential employers.  I guess I should take-up my other complaint (the "asking for additional information" message that doesn't tell me what information is requested) with Google.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We request your email address from your OpenID provider. You can change it at any time, including immediately after you register, by clicking the name/email link in the header.

Comment: +1 for answering the question, although I still maintain that, since OpenID won't verify for me that you're not uploading my entire life history, it's bad for for Careers to ask for info.  Better to limit search/application until user fills in required fields.  I'm a bit surprised that the responses about it have been so casual, as if "some website wants additional information from your account, but we're not going to show it to you" isn't a big deal.